# What is the following output from square API?

Tags: square-connect

I'm very new to this Square API and I'm not sure what the below output is. I have the Square API card form up and working in a sandbox. When I run a card I get the following output from the process-card.php.

What is the proition above the "Thank you for your payment"? Is this an error that is printing out or is it just informational? If it's just informational, can I just comment it out in the code or is there a different way to get to not display? I haven't been able to find any documenation on Square's site or on Google about this.

I used the files from [GitHub](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/php_payment)

Thanks.

```
SquareConnect\Model\ChargeResponse Object
(
    [errors:protected] => 
    [transaction:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Transaction Object
        (
            [id:protected] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            [location_id:protected] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            [created_at:protected] => 2017-04-04T15:32:45Z
            [tenders:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SquareConnect\Model\Tender Object
                        (
                            [id:protected] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                            [location_id:protected] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                            [transaction_id:protected] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                            [created_at:protected] => 2017-04-04T15:32:45Z
                            [note:protected] => Online Transaction
                            [amount_money:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Money Object
                                (
                                    [amount:protected] => 100
                                    [currency:protected] => USD
                                )

                            [processing_fee_money:protected] => 
                            [customer_id:protected] => 
                            [type:protected] => CARD
                            [card_details:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\TenderCardDetails Object
                                (
                                    [status:protected] => CAPTURED
                                    [card:protected] => SquareConnect\Model\Card Object
                                        (
                                            [id:protected] => 
                                            [card_brand:protected] => VISA
                                            [last_4:protected] => xxxx
                                            [exp_month:protected] => 
                                            [exp_year:protected] => 
                                            [cardholder_name:protected] => 
                                            [billing_address:protected] => 
                                        )

                                    [entry_method:protected] => KEYED
                                )

                            [cash_details:protected] => 
                        )

                )

            [refunds:protected] => 
            [reference_id:protected] => 
            [product:protected] => EXTERNAL_API
            [client_id:protected] => 
            [order:protected] => 
            [shipping_address:protected] => 
        )

)

Thank you for your payment.

Amount: $1.00
Card: VISA XXXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just informational to help you understand what is being returned from the API. The charge was processed successfully. If you remove the `print_r($response)` line, this will be hidden.